# getting json file generated by php to jquery - empty object - why?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have php file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(array('id' => 0, 'name' =>'test')));
```

it generates file like this:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"test"}]
```

then i pass it to jquery with:

```
    $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data + '\n' + data.status +':' + data.message);
            }
        });
```

but it generates:

```
[object Object]
undefined:undefined
```

Why? I also tried parseJSON function but with no result. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: when you console.log data you get [object Object] ?

Comment: Why is your object inside an array, if you are using it as if it isn't inside an array?

Comment: Are you using IE? If so, switch to Chrome and look at the console there. IE does a terrible job displaying objects

Comment: `console.log(data + '\n' + data.status +':' + data.message);` attempts to convert `data` to a string, yielding `[object Object]`. And in that JSON, there's no `status` or `message` property, hence they're `undefined`. Try just `console.log(data)`

Comment: you can output averything you wanted but use `,` like `console.log(data , '\n' , data.status , ':' , data.message);`

Comment: @NetaMeta I agree with this, pulled it into my answer.

Comment: netmeta console.log send [object Object] when i console.log(data)
michael_b i use chrome
blaze - how can i get data from object then? i used console.log(data) - it gives me [Object] and if i expand it: [Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON is an array, it should probably be:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                console.log(data[i] , '\n' , data[i].status , ':' , data[i].message);
            }
        }
 });
```

Comment: i changed array that i json_encode to:   echo json_encode(array(array('id' => 0, 'name' =>'test'), array('id' => 1, 'name' =>'abc'))); 
Using ur method i can now get all values i need by consoling it via data[i].id - that means for me that data is rather an array than object. can i somehow get to correct values via data.name.id for example data.abc.id and get 1 in response?

Comment: PHP isn't my primary language...You might need to create an object class then set the values of that class, and run `json_encode()` on that.